# JAVA ITextPdf, add text to rec

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

I have problem. I need to add text to my rectangle:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
canvas.rectangle(30, 20, 180, 90);
canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);         
canvas.setColorStroke(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
canvas.setLineWidth(2.5);
canvas.fill();
canvas.stroke();
```

I have tried this :

```
String text = "Sign-Up";
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();
canvas.beginText();

canvas.setFontAndSize(bf, 16);
canvas.moveText(30, 30);
canvas.moveTextWithLeading(0, -24);
canvas.showText(text);

canvas.endText();
```

But it does not work.

Comment: *But it does not work.* - what happens instead?

Comment: nothing... No error and "Sign-Up don't show...
Link how pdf look: http://www.pdf-archive.com/2015/06/06/34234-201506051658/

Comment: In case of your sample you have used "AWAY again", haven't you? Either your rectangle covers the writing or writing is inn the same color as the background, I cannot tell I. my cellular phone.

Comment: Thanks mkl, my rec cover writting text. Thanks for help :)